# Can't change UILabel's text from another View Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have two view controllers, one with a text field and a 'Next' button and another one with just a label. The idea is that you fill in your name in the text field and click 'Next'. It should then switch to the other view and the label should show your name.

When I switch views however, the label is just empty. I am rather new to Objective-C and I'm hoping someone knows why this is happening :).

ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController () {
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
}

-(IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    label.text = textField.text;
}

-(IBAction)remove:(id)sender {
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: In the code above, I only see one view controller, which doesn't mesh with your description.  But, a common mistake is to try to do something with an IBOutlet before it's been set.  An IBOutlet will be nil until the `-viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I meant to say I have one storyboard and inside that storyboard are two view controllers. I have only one ViewController.h and one ViewController.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you have two View Controllers. The first View Controller has an instance of UITextField, and a UIButton. Your second View Controller just has an instance of UILabel.

However, I noticed in your code that ViewController.m, which I am assuming is your first View Controller, has two IBOutlets, one for a UILabel and one for a UITextField, which doesn't make sense because the UILabel is supposed to be part of your second View Controller.

What you need to do is properly delete the IBOutlet for the UILabel from your first View Controller. Then, in your second View Controller, add the IBOutlet for it's UILabel.

Then, you need to implement the prepareForSegue method in your first View Controller and add a code statement like this:

```
[[segue destinationViewController]label].text = textField.text;
```

This way, when the segue is performed, you will successfully pass your first View Controller's text field's text to your second View Controller's label.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look up the prepareForSegue method. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Done! Again, for anyone who wants a visual explanation, check out this excellent tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5yA6ywgGbc